# Java Time Stamp unicode issue

Tags: java, unicode

While I'm trying to pass a timestamp as param for a post request, on Arabic phones etc., it seems to convert it into a unicode rather than a long. Can anyone explain me any theories behind this.

This is how I'm generating the time stamp string.

```
String timeStampString = String.format("%d",System.currentTimeMillis()/ 1000L);
```

But on server I'm getting unicode strings like `'\xd9\xa1\xd9\xa4\xd9\xa3\xd9\xa0\xd9\xa4\xd9\xa1\xd9\xa8\xd9
\xa8\xd9\xa2\xd9\xa0'`.

Comment: My params is `HashMap<String, String>`. I see what you are saying, but does that really matter? Why should a int/long value be converted to unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Formatter` class, which is used by `String.format()`, `PrintWriter.format()` and `PrintWriter.printf()`, is locale-sensitive.

This means that it will format numbers based on the default locale, if you do not give it an explicit locale.

Where the locale language is Arabic, depending on the locale provider being used, the number format may use digits that are "pure Arabic".

For example, take this little code snippet:

```
    int i = 1234567890;

    System.out.printf( "%d%n", i);
    Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
    System.out.printf( locale, "%d%n", i);
```

When the locale provider is the default one ("JRE"), it displays:

```
1234567890
1234567890
```

But if I run it with extended locale providers, like so:

```
java -Djava.locale.providers=CLDR SimpleTest
```

The output I get is:

```
1234567890
١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠
```

What you are seeing in your post parameter is the UTF-8 representation of these pure Arabic digits.

A simple solution would be to use an explicit locale. Instead of using

```
String.format("%d",System.currentTimeMillis()/ 1000L);
```

Use an English locale, where you are sure to get English<sup>(see note)</sup> digits.

```
String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d",System.currentTimeMillis()/ 1000L);
```

Or simply use `String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()/ 1000L)` or `Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()/ 1000L)` which are not locale-sensitive.

---

**Note:** The digits 0123456789 are actually called "Arabic Numerals", but this term would be confusing in this context, as the actual numerals used by the Arabic language are different (٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩).

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`String.valueOf(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-long-) instead:

String timeStampString = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);

Unlike `String.format`, that will always format using "regular" digits '0' to '9'.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Accepted @RealSkeptic's answer for explanation.